# How to rematch the first word or '(' the first word at the beginning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

str = "find().nodes() as n3" ==> find

str = "with n1,n2,n3" ===> with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string `match` with the regex pattern `^\w+`:

```js
var inputs = ["find().nodes() as n3", "with n1,n2,n3"];
inputs.forEach(x => console.log(x + " => " + x.match(/^\w+/)));
```

Comment: `\w` includes `_` as well, not sure if that is to be matched or not, +1

Comment: @CodeManiac Good point, and I'm happy to change my answer should the OP concur.

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem. For me it was all for loop concatenation